# Error StackOverflowError al imprimir en un txt y System.out.println usando recursividad

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una maquina de turing de que reconozca el lenguaje {0^n1^n | n>= 1}, ya habia quedado hecha pero mi profesor pide que probemos con una cadena de 1k, yo solo la habia probado con max 20, para rapido. En fin puse 1k y me salta StackOverflowError en cierto punto, me muevo por estados, nCad es mi variable de la acadena(cinta), y me muevo en ella con la variable cabezal, mis estados son casi iguales como este que pongo de ejemplo, el error lo da en el  System.out.println(ID); y en el f.write(ID+"\n"); , inicio la maquina llamandola asi estadoq0(0) porque empiezo en la posicion 0 de nCad, la otra es solo para imprimir de la forma que pide el profesor. si alguien puede ayudar lo agradeceria mucho :D

```
public void estadoq2(int posCabezal) throws IOException{
        //si le 0
        if (nCad.charAt(posCabezal) == '0') {
            //mantengo 0
            String ID = nEnt.substring(0, posCabezal - 1) + "(q2)" + nEnt.substring(posCabezal - 1) + " ├";
            f.write(ID+"\n");
            System.out.println(ID);
            posCabezal-=1;
            estadoq2(posCabezal);
        }//si lee X
        else if (nCad.charAt(posCabezal) == 'X') {
            //mantengo la X
             String ID = nEnt.substring(0, posCabezal + 1) + "(q2)" + nEnt.substring(posCabezal + 1) + " ├";
             f.write(ID+"\n");
             System.out.println(ID);
             posCabezal+=1;
             estadoq0(posCabezal);
        }//si lee Y
        else if (nCad.charAt(posCabezal) == 'Y') {
             String ID = nEnt.substring(0, posCabezal - 1) + "(q2)" + nEnt.substring(posCabezal - 1) + " ├";
             f.write(ID+"\n");
             System.out.println(ID);
             posCabezal-=1;
             estadoq2(posCabezal);
        }else{
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            f.write("ERROR"+"\n");
            stop(false);
        } 
    }
El error que me da:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.nio.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:241)
    at java.base/java.nio.CharBuffer.<init>(CharBuffer.java:286)
    at java.base/java.nio.HeapCharBuffer.<init>(HeapCharBuffer.java:78)
    at java.base/java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:406)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:289)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.base/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:226)
    at java.base/java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:249)
    at Practica.General.estadoq2(General.java:96)
    at Practica.General.estadoq2(General.java:99)
    at Practica.General.estadoq2(General.java:99)
```

Comment: El error de StackOverflow se debe a que el stack de la aplicacióon se sobrepasó debido a una recursión exhaustiva.
Tu algoritmo funciona bien para entradas relativamente pequeñas (longitud 20 como indicaste). Pero cuando aumentas el tamaño de la entrada 1K como indicó tu profesor, se deja ver la poca eficiencia en términos de memoria que tiene un algoritmo recursivo. Lo que te recomiendo que hagas es que conviertas tu algoritmo recursivo en uno iterativo, esto permitirá ahorrar memoria en tiempo de ejecución (si lo diseñas bien por supuesto)